# How would you say "the ___ family"?

Tags: expressions

So in English, we might talk about a family by saying (for example) "the Johnson family" or "the Johnsons." Is there an equivalent you use in Japanese? And would you use the same language when talking to a member of the family you're referring to and when talking about that family to a third party?

Thanks!

Comment: 息子、家族へようこそ
Welcome to the family, son.

Comment: What is that supposed to be?

Comment: Look at the user name ("Dad").  That, the comment, and the lack of other answers seems to suggest it was intended as a joke rather than as a real answer.  I will guiltily admit I giggled a little.

Answer (score 8):

Let us suppose the family name is [山田]{やまだ}.

Most commonly, we would say:

> 「山田[家]{け}」 ← 「家」 is read 「**け**」 for this usage.
>
> 「山田[一家]{いっか}」

***Formally***, we could say:

> 「山田[一族]{いちぞく}」

「一族」is not an everyday word.  It could sound too dramatic or theatrical if used in a casual convo.

> "And would you use the same language when talking to a member of the family you're referring to and when talking about that family to a third party?"

The same phrase can be used on both occasions.

[image]
<sub>(source: [k-img.com](http://image.eiga.k-img.com/images/movie/83447/poster2/200.jpg?1457577317))</sub>
  [image]
<sub>(source: [so-net.ne.jp](http://silvercopen2.c.blog.so-net.ne.jp/_images/blog/_e73/silvercopen2/E382B9E382AFE383AAE383BCE383B3E382B7E383A7E38383E38388EFBC882011-07-142019.01.47EFBC89.png?c=a0))</sub>

Comment: Bonus: although uncommon in real life, [一族]{いちぞく} might be seen more often in fictional work such as the anime *Naruto*, where it is the word of choice for this.